# Android AWS SDK returning only one EC2 Instance instead of a list

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I'm new to Android but I've already used AWS SDK for PHP previously and I never had this kind of a problem. I'm using DescribeInstancesRequest to fetch a list of all instances and their statuses. Idea is to have a list of all instances with ToggleButton for start/stop operations. Over AsyncTask I'm executing request to AWS like this:

```
private class LoadInstancesListTask extends AsyncTask<DescribeInstancesRequest, Void, DescribeInstancesResult> {

    private Context ctx;

    public void setContext(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected DescribeInstancesResult doInBackground(DescribeInstancesRequest... params) {
        DescribeInstancesRequest request = params[0];
        AmazonEC2AsyncClient client = new AmazonEC2AsyncClient(request.getRequestCredentials());
        client.setEndpoint("ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
        DescribeInstancesResult response = client.describeInstances(request);
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DescribeInstancesResult response) {
        Reservation reservation = response.getReservations().get(0);
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, reservation.toString());
        InstanceListAdapter adapter = new InstanceListAdapter(this.ctx, R.layout.instance_list_row_layout, reservation.getInstances());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Thing is I'm getting only 1 EC2 instance in response instance list instead of all 4 I'm currently using. Anyone had similar problem or know another way of fetching a list of instances from AWS SDK?

I'll appreciate any help - thanks.

Comment: I don't know the Amazon API, but with this `response.getReservations().get(0)` I'd say you are only retreiving index 0 from the response, and that is probably why you don't get all.

Comment: @chrkad thanks! I thought that all instances comes under single reservation and althogh I did checked the instance list into single reservation I totally forgot to check if there are other reservations :)

Answer (score 1):

As @chrkad pointed in the comment I was looking only to the first reservation instead processing all of them. Thanks again :)